# Is there a simple way to tell whether another user has access to a file with the HCL Connections Files API?

Tags: ibm-connections, hcl-connections

I need to detect whether another user can open a file from HCL Connections Files.

Is there a single request that can be made to retrieve a particular user's access to a File?

The acls=true parameter listed [here](https://ds_infolib.hcltechsw.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=HCL+Connections+6.0+CR6+API+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Retrieving_file_metadata_hc60&content=apicontent) retrieves access for the current user. Ideally I'd like to specify another userId to retrieve access for.

Otherwise I'm going to run through and check the several ways that a user can have access to a file (Explicit permission, permission via community, library owner, public file visibility).